# At what age get a child to stop using pullups at night? [merged]

Tags: behavior, sleep, bedroom

At what age get a child to stop using pullups at night? And how do you encourage a child and give them the confidence to try sleeping without one? I know one OK way is telling them it's Ok to wet the bed. Any other techniques?